# In C language, what's the purpose of statement that is after return?

Tags: c, type-conversion

Recently I read the code of one public C library and found below function definition:

```
void* block_alloc(void** block, size_t* len, size_t type_size)
{
    return malloc(type_size);

    (void)block;
    (void)len;
}
```

I wonder whether it will arrive at the statements after return. If not, what's the purpose of these 2 statements that convert some data to void ?

Comment: presumably to silence compiler unused var warnings? and no, no statements can be reached after the return statement in a method/function.

Comment: I assume it is a requirement that `block_alloc` have this specific signature but it doesn't actually need `block` or `len`, so `(void)block` and `(void)len` suppress any "unused variable" warnings.

Comment: It's pretty stupid to place those casts at the end of the function, because now you might get different warnings about unreachable code instead. The casts should be placed at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 4):

As Basil notes, the `(void)` statements are likely intended to silence compiler warnings about the unused parameters. But - you can move the `(void)` statements before the `return` to make them less confusing, and with the same effect.

In fact, there's yet another way to achieve the same effect, without resorting to any extra statements. It's supported by many compilers already today, although it's not officially in the C standard before C2X:

```
void* block_alloc(void**, size_t*, size_t type_size)
{
    return malloc(type_size);
}
```

if you don't name the parameters, typical compilers don't expect you to be using them.

Comment: In C it seems like omitting the param name is non-standard (apparently until C23): https://godbolt.org/z/9Ybf8s619

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: Thanks for pointing this out, I guess I'm too used to C++ by now.

Answer (score 3):

First, these statements appearing in the block after a `return` will never be executed.

Check by reading some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Second, on some compilers (perhaps [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra`) the useless statements might avoid some warnings.

In my opinion, coding these statements before the return won't change the machine code emitted by an optimizing compiler (use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` to check and emit the assembler code) and makes the C source code more understandable.

GCC provides, as an extension, [the variable `__attribute__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) named `unused`.

Perhaps in your software your `block_alloc` is assigned to some important function pointer (whose signature is requested)

Comment: a slightly longer version of my comment above.

Comment: But I added hyperlinks to interesting information.

Answer (score 3):

It is used to silence the warnings. Some programming standards required all the parameters to be used in the function body, and their static analyzers will not pass the code without it.

It is added after the return to prevent a generation of the code in some circumstances:

```
int foo(volatile unsigned x)
{
    (void)x;
    return 0;
}

int foo1(volatile unsigned x)
{
    return 0;
    (void)x;
}
```

```
foo:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
foo1:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], edi
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```